# Python 2.7 to 3.4 Subprocess Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm calling another program with a piece of code that looks like this:

```
import subprocess
lc="/package/bin/program --do stuff"
command_list = lc.split()
ljs=subprocess.Popen(command_list,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ljs.communicate()[0]
```

The string works fine at the UNIX command line and the code works in Python 2.7. But, in Python 3.4, I get an error like this:

```
File "/package/bin/program", line 2, in <module>
    from package import module
ImportError: No module named package
```

"/package/bin/program" is calling a dependency from another file in the package here, which I think is the core issue. I have calls to other programs that are working fine in 3.4.

What's changed in 3.4 that might be causing this?

(Sorry in advance for the cryptic code - I'm calling company internal tools that I can't expose here).

Comment: Does the file `bin/program` exist in current working directory?

Comment: I assume `bin/program` is a python 2.7 app? Maybe there is something in the environment you pass down to the subprocess that causes it to look in the 3.4 path for modules. Check what's in `os.environ`, especially PYTHONPATH. You could also look at the first line in `bin/package` to see if its "shebang" is pointing to the right python.

Comment: Oh, and I assume you are not doing this in a virtual environment?

Comment: @falsetru no but im calling the whole path. Update post.

Comment: @tdelaney you're right, the target app is 2.7. Let me dig into that. Thanks!

Comment: You could write a test app that replaces `program` and pokes around the `sys` module to see things like version and what's in `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the working directory of the subproccess instance is default the directory of bash shell. To set a new working directory, set the `cwd` argument in your `Popen` to your working directory.

Here's an example:

```
subprocess.Popen(['random' '--command'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, cwd='C:/Path/To/Working/Directory/')
```

Comment: OP's problem is with `program` importing other modules. I don't see how current working directory is involved.

Comment: @tdelaney Because from what I can see, there is no importing except in the Popen. So he must be running a Python script in the Popen and the script imports stuff. In that case... the code he has posted is irrelevant.

Comment: `program` imports stuff. But regardless, cwd is not involved.

Comment: @tdelaney So that means we cannot debug without looking into the company's code, and that my answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Comments above have been helpful in exploring the issue, but at the end of the day this seems to be some permissions conflict - adding a `sudo -u <user>` before the command fixes the issue. Still not clear why Py3 requires this and Py2 doesn't, but perhaps I need to explore the issue more closely with other internal users.

Thanks!